# Construct an analytic function f in |z|<R such that f has zeroes only at z=-R +1/n $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, meromorphic-functions

This question is from Ponnusamy and Silvermann's Complex variables with applications ( Chapter : Entire and meromorphic functions).

> Construct an analytic function f in |z|<R such that f has zeroes only at z=-R +1/n $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I can 't use weierstrass's product theorem as sequence has a finite ;limit point . Also , $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  1/{a_n}^p $ will diverge for all p , where $a_n$= -R+1/n so , f(z) = $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-z/a_n) \times exp(z+ z^2 /2 +z^3/3 + z^p/p)$ can't be the required function.

I don't have any other ideas on how to find the series.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Rudin proves in (RCA) given any set without limit points in a domain there exists an analytic function with zeros precisely at the points of that set.

Comment: $\sin(\frac{\pi}{z+R})$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ya, But I am afraid that your mentioned result can't be used here as the sequence mention ed here has limit point which is finite!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Also looking at the comment of User :Muse_China It seems there was no need of any complex analysis. AM I right ?

Comment: It has no limit point in $\Omega =\{z: |z|<R\}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you please answer question raised by me in my 2nd comment also?

Comment: Muse_China is right.

Comment: @Muse_China But in your answer z=-R-1/n , $\mathbb{N}$ are also zeroes. So,It's not correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It also has roots at z=-R-1/n .

Comment: @Ben But you say that the function is in $|z| < R$.

Comment: @Ben You may set $f(z) = 1$ when $|z| \geq R$, since $f(z)$ is not required to be analytic on $|z| \geq R$.